# Jquery selector for .each function

Tags: jquery, iteration

I have table which has a class "data" and it has table rows inside it's tablebody as it should be.

By jquery, I want to apply a masking plugin function to the each input text of its row.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
$('.data tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this, "input:checkbox").setMask();
});
```

Comment: you can simplu use `$('.data input:checkbox').setMask()` instead of that selector & loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the arguments are in the wrong order... switch em around for the setMask invocation.

Comment: $("input:checkbox", this).setMask(); Doesn't seem to be working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

can you not simply use this:

```
$('.data tbody tr input:checkbox').setMask();
```

as this should give the same result but in 1 single context.

If that still does not work, try the following:

```
try{
    $('.data tbody tr input:checkbox').setMask();
}catch(the_error){
    $('body').text(the_error);
    alert("Error: " + the_error);
}
```

and then send us what's outputted.